# How can I restrict a twilio number to be used only for SMS

Tags: twilio

Is it possible to remove every capability other than SMS (i.e. Voice/MMS/FAX) from Twilio number (not the whole account)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you remove the webhook URL from the Voice section of the number config, then the number will not respond to incoming calls whatsoever. Alternatively you could add a [TwiML Bin](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/tutorials/twiml-bins) response to return the [`<Reject>` verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/reject) which rejects incoming calls without billing you. Numbers can only do either voice or fax, so if it is set to voice it won't respond to fax.

The only thing here is that if you are using a number in the US or Canada for SMS, then those numbers automatically accept MMS messages as well. You can ignore the media and never send out media messages yourself, but you can't stop receiving those MMS messages if you are receiving SMS messages. If you are using a number anywhere else in the world, Twilio doesn't accept MMS messages on those numbers, so you are sorted there.

Comment: Sorry for not detailing this in my original message, but I am referring to outgoing capabilities, e.g. outgoing voice calls.

Comment: Your application is responsible for interacting with the Twilio API and performing outbound actions. So if your application only sends outbound SMS messages then you won't be making phone calls or sending MMS.